# How to change theme for checkbox in toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I use `Toolbar` and `Menu` in my class.

Here is the `menu_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_checkbox"
        android:title="checkbox"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</group>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_delete"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_delete"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_rename"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_rename"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_copy"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_copy"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_new_folder"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_new_folder"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

And here is what it is now:

[image]
[image]

How should i do to change the theme for checkbox in toolbar? I hope it can be white when checked.

Comment: are you doing any handling in Java when user presses the checkbox? If so, can you show the code here on what you do when `AppCompatCheckBox` is pressed?

Comment: No, i didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can change checkbox color directly in the xml. Use buttonTint value for the box: (as of API level 23)

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:buttonTint="@color/CHECK_COLOR" />
```

You can  also do this using appCompatCheckbox v7 for older APIs:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:buttonTint="@color/COLOR_HERE" />
```